# Radio Button setOnChangeListener not working inside fragment

Tags: android

I want to check whether the radio button is checked then do. But inside fragment this is not working I cannot figure out because of why? If any one can help appreciate it very much!

My fragment:

```
public class OneFragment extends Fragment {

RadioGroup radioFanStatus;
RadioButton radioButtonOn;
RadioButton radioButtonOff;
View inflateView;
TabDisplay tabDisplay;
public OneFragment()
{
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   inflateView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);

   radioFanStatus = (RadioGroup)inflateView.findViewById(R.id.radioOnOff);
   radioButtonOn=(RadioButton)inflateView.findViewById(R.id.radioFanOn);
   radioButtonOff=(RadioButton)inflateView.findViewById(R.id.radioFanOff);


       radioFanStatus.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"On",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         // Log.e("",""+checkedId);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"On"+checkedId+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
           if(checkedId ==R.id.radioFanOn)
           {
               Toast.makeText(getContext(),"On"+checkedId+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                ((TabDisplay)getActivity()).functionFanOn();
                 Log.e("","on");
           }
           else  if(checkedId ==R.id.radioFanOff)
           {
               Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Off"+checkedId+"",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               ((TabDisplay)getActivity()).functionFanOff();
                Log.e("","off");
           }
           else
           {

           }
        }
   });
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
}

}
```

This is my xml related to the fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Change staus"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioOnOff"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioFanOn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="On"
        />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioFanOff"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Off" />


</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: What isn't working exactly? Do you have any errors? What have you tried to fix it? Please read and follow the instructions on this page to produce a high-quality question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
```

to

```
return inflateView;
```

Now you are inflating the layout twice.

Comment: yes!!! this was worked!! thank you so much,I have wasted lot of time to do this.once again thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Please accept the answer if it was helpful